# Как вставить функцию в документе

Tags: javascript

Я панимаю, вопрос банальный. Но ни как не могу найти на него ответ.
У меня есть функция в отдельном документе, сам документ я уже прикрутил к html странице.
А как вставить данную функцию в нужном месте документа не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вопроса толком нифига не понять, но попробую... У вас javascript функция сохранена в отдельном файле, вы ее подключили в HTML документе

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="путь до файла"></script>
```

Теперь вы не знаете как вызвать свою функцию ? Если так, то

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function_name();
</script>
```

function_name - это название вашей функции